# If I open a raw socket and start reading the packets, are the packets that have been read not delivered to the destined TCP sockets?

Tags: tcp, raw-sockets

I think the question explains it fully.

Another way to say it: Are the packets read via a raw socket removed from the communication channel completely, so that they are not even delivered to the TCP socket that they were intended for in the first place. For e.g., if there is a web server running on my host, listening on port 80, and I open a raw socket listening for all TCP protocol packets, will the web server never receive those packets being sent to port 80?

Thanks.

Comment: A RAW socket is commonly used to enable promiscuous listening (packet sniffing), in which case, packets are still delivered to the target socket, as well as to the RAW socket.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience packets read on the raw socket are not removed from the communication. You could even have multiple raw sockets at the same time and all get the same packages. But to cite from [Linux: man raw](https://linux.die.net/man/7/raw):

> Raw sockets may tap all IP protocols in Linux, even protocols like ICMP or TCP which have a protocol module in the kernel. In this case, the packets are **passed to both the kernel module and the raw socket(s)**. **This should not be relied upon in portable programs**, many other BSD socket implementation have limitations here.